# SwiftUI how can I have the Textfield right on top of the keyboard with any spaces

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am using SwiftUI 4.0 and I am trying to replicate a feature that most social apps have for editing photos (Instagram & Snapchat) . Essentially you select a photo and then you press a button and you are able to write on that photo . My issue is with the TextField not appearing right on top of the keyboard . There is a space between the keyboard and Textfield that I would like to eliminate . What I am trying to do is simply have the textfield appear right on top of the keyboard . The image below will illustrate my issue . As you can see from the image below there is a gap between the Hello World and the keyboard . I would like the KeyBoard to come right up under the Textfield .

This is my current code below and also in the info.plist I had to add the privacy - photo library usage description .Any suggestions would be great .

```
import SwiftUI
import PhotosUI

struct KeyBoardOverlay: View {
    @FocusState private var isTextFieldFocused: Bool
    @State var text = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        
        TextField("", text: $text)
            .focused($isTextFieldFocused)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .background(Color.black.opacity(0.7))
            .keyboardType(.alphabet)
            .disableAutocorrection(true)
        HStack {
            
            
            Button(action: {
                isTextFieldFocused = true
               
                  }) {
                   
                  }
              
            }
        .padding([.vertical], 10)
        .padding([.horizontal], 15) /
        .background(Color.black.opacity(0.4))
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25))
    }
}

struct ShowImageView: View {
    @State private var selectedItem: [PhotosPickerItem] = []
    @State private var mediaData: Data?
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            PhotosPicker(selection: $selectedItem,
                         maxSelectionCount: 1,
                         matching: .any(of: [.images])) {
                Image(systemName: "photo")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
                    .foregroundColor(Color(.black))
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
            }.onChange(of: selectedItem) { newMedia in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    guard let item = selectedItem.first else {
                        return
                    }

                        item.loadTransferable(type: Data.self) { result in
                            switch result {
                            case .success(let data):
                                if let data = data {
                                    
                                    self.mediaData = data
                                    
                                } else {
                                    print("data is nil")
                                }
                            case .failure(let failure):
                                fatalError("\(failure)")
                            }
                        }
                    
                }
            }
            if let data = mediaData, let uiimage = UIImage(data: data) {
                Image(uiImage: uiimage)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .padding(.top, 10)
                    .overlay(
                        VStack {
                            KeyBoardOverlay()
                            
                        }.padding(.bottom), alignment: .bottom)

            }
   
        }
    }
}
```

This is how it looks now
[image: My Image]

something like this
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Apply `.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard, edges: .bottom)` to your `TextField`.